# Removed file too large, returns error

Tags: git, github, github-pages, github-for-mac

I just started learning how to use git, so I'm sorry if I don't give enough info/give useless info.

I'm trying to push my changes to Github using the Github Desktop application, but I added (and committed) a very large file, so it returns an error (max is 100MB). I then removed the files causing the error, and committed again, and I still get the error.

Comment: Have you just removed the file but not reset your commit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run `git reset --soft`, then re-commit.